# Elegant way to make a SUm

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need a query (in Oracle), that will be inside a stored procedure, where I can get a sum of the Amount value of Table REV.

The YEAR and one MONTH will be received as a parameter in the stored procedure, as YY and MM.

What I want is to sum the amount values since the 1st month of the year UP to the MM passed in the argument.

So

- if MM in the argument is 02, I want to take the sum of amounts of months 01 + 02
- if MM in the argument is 05, I want to take the sum of amounts of months 01+02+03+04+05

So MM is the last month to be summed.

How can I make this in the most efficient and elegant way?

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "GET_YTD_AMOUNT" (YY in VARCHAR,
                                                 MM in VARCHAR)

 select
     ACT.LABEL ,
     R.YEAR,
     R.MONTH,
     sum(R.AMOUNT)
    from 
    ACTIVITY ACT,
    REV R

    where 
    R.YEAR=YEAR and 
    R.MONTH ??
    R.ID_CODE = ACT.ID_CODE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use less than equal to:

```
select
     ACT.LABEL ,
     R.YEAR,
     Max(R.MONTH) || '-' ||  Max(R.MONTH) as months_from_to
     sum(R.AMOUNT)
    from 
    ACTIVITY ACT,
    REV R

  where 
    R.YEAR= YY and -- it should be YY
    R.MONTH <= MM -- less than equal to with MM
    R.ID_CODE = ACT.ID_CODE
Group by ACT.LABEL ,
         R.YEAR
```

**Note**: You must re-design your DB to store dates in `date` data type.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer using numeric variables rather than strings for such cases.

In your case ;

- considering your year and month parameters are of string type, you need a `to_number()` conversion with less than or equal to operator 
  `to_number(R.MONTH) <= to_number(i_month)`
- add an `out` parameter `o_amount` to return the result you get
- of course, you need to convert your SQL format containing explicit
  joins
- better to define parameters ( or local variables ) by their type
  within the tables in which they're contained. Btw, I didn't define `o_amount` by `rev.amount%type` against probability of `sum()` aggregation might exceed the precision of numeric value provided it's defined as so within the table.

So,use :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_YTD_AMOUNT( 
                                           i_year   in rev.year%type, 
                                           i_month  in rev.month%type, 
                                           o_amount out number
                                           ) IS
BEGIN
  select sum(r.amount) 
    into o_amount
    from activity a
    join rev r
      on r.id_code = a.id_code 
   where r.year = i_year 
     and to_number(r.month) <= to_number(i_month); 
END;
/
```